# shared_ptr deletes the object

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

```
void ClassName::LocalMethod( )
{
    boost::shared_ptr<ClassName> classNamePtr( this );

    //some operation with classNamePtr
    return;
}
```

Here the object is getting released when it returns from LocalMethod() since classNamePtr is out of scope. Isn't the shared_ptr smart enough to know that the ClassName object is still in scope and not to delete it?

Comment: "Let me know the correct way to go about this" - to go about what?  What exactly is it you're trying to do?  One way might be to simply not use a `shared_ptr` and simply use `this` (or the members of the object directly, without `this->`).  But presumably you were try to use `shared_ptr` for some reason - maybe ask about that more directly.

Comment: Question: why are you creating a shared_ptr in the first place?

Comment: The correct way to go about this is most likely redesign.  Why do you need a shared_ptr to an object that's not dynamically allocated?

Answer (score 4):

What does it mean to create a `shared_ptr` to an object? It means that the holder of the `shared_ptr` now assumes ownership over the object. Ownership meaning that the object will be deleted when he so desires. When the holder of the `shared_ptr` destroys its `shared_ptr`, that will cause the object to potentially be destroyed, assuming that there are no other `shared_ptr`s to that object.

When a `shared_ptr` is a member of a class, that means that the lifetime of the object pointed to by the `shared_ptr` is *at least* as long as the object that the `shared_ptr` is a member of. When a `shared_ptr` is on the stack, this means that the lifetime of the object that the `shared_ptr` is pointing to will be at least as long as the scope it was created in. Once the object falls off the stack, it may be deleted.

The *only* time you should ever take a pointer and wrap it into a `shared_ptr` is when you are *allocating* the object *initially*. Why? Because an object does not know whether it is in a `shared_ptr` or not. It can't know. This means that the person who creates the original `shared_ptr` now has the responsibility to pass it around to other people who need to share ownership of that memory. The only way shared ownership works is through the *copy constructor* of `shared_ptr`. For example:

```
shared_ptr<int> p1 = new int(12);
shared_ptr<int> p2 = p1.get();
shared_ptr<int> p3 = p1;
```

The copy constructor of `shared_ptr` creates shared ownership between `p1` and `p3`. Note that `p2` *does not share ownership* with `p1`. They both think they have ownership over the same memory, but that's not the same as sharing it. Because they both think that they have *unique* ownership of it.

Therefore, when the three pointers are destroyed, the following will happen. First, `p3` will be destroyed. But since p3 and p1 share ownership of the integer, the integer will not be destroyed yet. Next, `p2` will be destroyed. Since it thinks that it is the only holder of the integer, it will then destroy it.

At this point, `p1` is pointing to deleted memory. When `p1` is destroyed, it thinks that it is the only holder of the integer, so it will then destroy it. This is **bad**, since it was already destroyed.

Your problem is this. You are inside an instance of a class. And you need to call some functions of yours that take a `shared_ptr`. But all you have is `this`, which is a regular pointer. What do you do?

You're going to get some examples that suggest `enable_shared_from_this`. But consider a more relevant question: "why do those functions take a `shared_ptr` as an argument?"

The type of pointer a function takes is indicative of what that function does with its argument. If a function takes a `shared_ptr`, that means that it needs to *own* the pointer. It needs to take shared ownership of the memory. So, look at your code and ask whether those functions truly *need* to take ownership of the memory. Are they storing the `shared_ptr` somewhere long-term (ie: in an object), or are they just using them for the duration of the function call?

If it's the latter, then the functions should take a naked pointer, not a `shared_ptr`. That way, they *cannot* claim ownership. Your interface is then self-documenting: the pointer type explains ownership.

However, it is possible that you could be calling functions that truly do need to take shared ownership. Then you need to use `enable_shared_from_this`. First, your class needs to be derived from `enable_shared_from_this`. Then, in the function:

```
void ClassName::LocalMethod()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<ClassName> classNamePtr(shared_from_this());

    //some operation with classNamePtr
    return;
}
```

Note that there is a cost here. `enable_shared_from_this` puts a `boost::weak_ptr` in the class. But there is no virtual overhead or somesuch; it doesn't make the class virtual. `enable_shared_from_this` is a template, so you have to declare it like this:

```
class ClassName : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<ClassName>
```

Comment: The only thing to keep in mind with `enable_shared_from_this` is that you must have placed the object in a `shared_ptr` at some point prior to calling `shared_from_this()`.   I usually enforce this by creating a static factory method that returns a shared pointer and make the original constructor private.

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't the shared_ptr smart enough to know that the ClassName object is
>   still in scope and not to delete it?

That's not how `shared_ptr` works. When you pass a pointer while constructing a `shared_ptr`, the `shared_ptr` will assume *ownership* of the pointee (in this case, `*this`). In other words, the `shared_ptr` assumes total control over the lifetime of the pointee by virtue of the fact that the `shared_ptr` now owns it. Because of this, the last `shared_ptr` owning the pointee will delete it.

**If there will be no copies of `classNamePtr` outside of `ClassName::LocalMethod()`,** you can pass a deleter that does nothing while constructing `classNamePtr`. [Here's an example of a custom deleter being used to prevent a `shared_ptr` from deleting its pointee](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#static). Adapting the example to your situation:

```
struct null_deleter // Does nothing
{
    void operator()(void const*) const {}
};

void ClassName::LocalMethod() 
{
    // Construct a shared_ptr to this, but make it so that it doesn't
    // delete the pointee.
    boost::shared_ptr<ClassName> classNamePtr(this, null_deleter()); 
    // Some operation with classNamePtr 

    // The only shared_ptr here will go away as the stack unwinds,
    // but because of the null deleter it won't delete this.
    return; 
}
```

You can also use [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) to obtain a `shared_ptr` from `this`. Note that the member function `shared_from_this()` only works if you have an existing `shared_ptr` already pointing to `this`.

```
class ClassName : public enable_shared_from_this<ClassName> 
{ 
public: 
    void LocalMethod()
    { 
        boost::shared_ptr<ClassName> classNamePtr = shared_from_this(); 
    } 
} 

// ...

// This must have been declared somewhere...
shared_ptr<ClassName> p(new ClassName);
// before you call this:
p->LocalMethod();
```

This is the more appropriate, "official" method and it's much less hackish than the null deleter method.

It could also be that you don't actually need to create a `shared_ptr` in the first place. What goes into the section commented `//some operation with classNamePtr`? There might be an even better way than the first two ways.

Comment: I don't believe in the null-deleter method. If those functions he is calling expect to claim ownership of the object, then using a null-deleter-based function won't allow them to do so. They could be pointing at dead memory later. And if the functions _don't_ take ownership, then why do they take a `shared_ptr` to begin with?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: That's why I said "If there will be no copies of `classNamePtr` outside of `ClassName::LocalMethod()`". If I knew what goes into section commented "//some operation with classNamePtr", I can give an even better suggestion. That being said, I did edit the answer to point out that the `enabled_shared_from_this` is more apropriate and the OP should reconsider the overall design.